# Is it possible to insert code between the condition and the body of a while loop?

Tags: loops, syntax, while-loop

Is it possible to do something like what is shown in the code below (in any language)?

```
while(Condition)
// can I do anything here (like initializations) between the condition and the body of the loop?
{
   // while Loop body
}
```

Comment: yes you can write there , but the block after that will not be considered the body of loop ..

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't specified a language...

In Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp, the [loop](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) macro supports an `initially` clause that could do what you want here.

```
(loop while (my-predicate)
      initially (perform-setup)
      do (my-function))
```

This clause clause executes outside the loop (i.e. only once).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not possible, at least in any language I know of (and that covers a lot of them)

To simulate the same effect:

```
bool firstTime = true;
while (condition)
{
    if (firstTime)
    {
        // do initialization here
        firstTime = false
    }
    //  the rest of your loop stuff here
}
```

That will do what you want, but it's not exactly the same in terms of performance because there is an additional comparison happening in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in any language I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possisble atleast in java

```
while(Condition)
// You can't do anything here
{
// This is the While Loop body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.it's not possible to initialize variable or anything after while loop and before body of while loop.And if you do like

```
boolean a;
while(condition)
   a=false;
{
//body of loop
}
```

then `a=false` will become body of while loop and

```
{
//body of loop
}
```

will not be part of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by

```
for(int i=0,x=1,c=3;print(i,x,c),i<15;i++)
{
//use i,x,c here ,where they are initialized once
}
```

**output:**
print(i,x,c) will execute once

This works in C#

Comment: It works, except it's not a while-loop, which is what the question is (currently) asking.